# Adding / removing content to a div without reloading

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

can you please send me some advice about such a situation:

1. I have DB with user comments
2. I have a div with 10 last comments added
3. I would like to refresh this div each 3 seconds, BUT I don’t want to refresh all div – I would like to add new comment / or comments to div and remove redundant comments.

So, now i have something like that:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
     $('#commentdiv').load('loadcomments.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 3000); 

<div id="commentdiv'"></div>
```

And it works fine, but it refresh all div, i would like “only” to load new comments and push it to a div + pop out redutant comments.

Regards,
Luke

Comment: We cannot help with that little information you provide. You did not show your page structure, so the html markup. All we can say is the general advice: don't fade in the `div`, obviously, but instead add to the content of that `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to store last loaded comment id on the screen. When you want
  to refresh div for a new comments, you can send a last loaded comment
  id via query string like `loadcomments.php?last_id=5`.
- On the `loadcomments.php` you can get the last id and you can create
  query like the following:

  ```
  SELECT * 
  FROM comments 
  WHERE id > 5 
    AND article_id = 2
  ```